# Psychic girl who can read thoughts by touch!

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, psychic

I'm looking for a book, but I only read the first chapter and I don't remember much, but here's what I do remember:

- The main character was a girl who recently moved to a new town, I think it was because her mother remarried, but I'm not sure.
- The girl was kinda-psychic. She could read people's thoughts when she touched them, a talent she got from her father, who died when she was younger.
- There was a guy in the story who could also read thoughts by touch. She discovered this when he touched her and they held a conversation without talking out loud.

I know it's not much, but please help!!!

Comment: Might need just a *little* more detail, if you could.  Without the "recently moved" part, and the [tag:young-adult] tag, it almost sounds like the character you're talking about is [Sookie Stackhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sookie_Stackhouse) but I'm sure you'd remember that a bit better.  And, I'm pretty sure her history wasn't covered in the first chapter of the series.  Can you remember any other events that took place in the first chapter?  Anything particular about this other guy, or something else that set the stage for the ensuing plot?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be Evermore by Alyson Noel. You can read a synopsis on Goodreads...https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3975774-evermore

It features female central character who moves to a new town as you describe and who can see thoughts by touching a person as you mention.